# GAS Webapp/Dialog returning unexpected results

Tags: google-apps-script

dialogs seem to use the same interface web wise as the webapps, in other words a front html/javascript and a backend google apps script.

I'm getting some unexpected behavior if I try to return an array made from my spreadsheet rather than a straight up array.

This is my code

```
function returnRowArray(number){
  if (number == null) number = 4;
  thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TST Project Tracker");
  console.log("L4 returnRowArray(): %s", number);
  var headerRow = thisSheet.getRange("A1:DC1").getValues();
  var resultRow = thisSheet.getRange(number,1,1,20).getValues();
  var result = {}
  result.info = resultRow[0][1];
  result.site = site;
  //result.row = resultRow;//LINE IN QUESTION
  console.log("L10: %s", JSON.stringify(result));
  return result;
  }
```

If I run this function from my dialog WITH the line in question, it returns null to the dialog box, but with the line commented out it returns the object correctly.

the two CLIENT SIDE logged results show up as

> L35: null

and

> L35: Object

respectively, and I can pull the values out of the object.

If I run a SERVER SIDE test

```
function test_returnRowArray(){
  var o = returnRowArray(4);
  console.log("L15: "+o);
  console.log("L16: "+ JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

it provides the correct result for both versions.

So what is going on here? I originally thought it was a size restriction but even when I do what I've done here, make the array just the first 20 columns, this still happens.

Any ideas?

edit: I will note if I make it result.row = ["this","array","works"] it does work, so how is the getrange array making it angry?

Adding per comments:

This is what the front end call looks like

```
  function importInfo(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result){console.log("L35: %s", result);}).returnRowArray(row);
```

}

Comment: Note, I can force it to work by doing a join on the array when I pass it back, but that doesn't answer the question of how a getValues() array is being perceived as different from a hand built one.

Comment: Dumb idea, but did you check what's inside the object? JS historically identifies null as an object, maybe it's the case?

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the script of your HTML&Javascript side? I would like to confirm the method for calling the function of `returnRowArray()` and retrieving the values from the function.

Comment: How does the `resultRow` array look like?

Comment: resultRow is just an array of the data from this row, in this example there were no commas in any of that data, a mix of strings and numbers/dates like: [1345, "BBB","Clean the windows",1/2/21,"no","Bob Smith", "n/a", "Planning"] etc

Comment: Thank you for replying. Where can I see the script for `the two CLIENT SIDE logged` in your question? And also, when `result` of `withSuccessHandler(function(result){console.log("L35: %s", result);})` is the object, in this case, please use `JSON.stringify` like `console.log("L35: %s", JSON.stringify(result))`.

Comment: My suspicion here is that this is related to your data and - moreover, did Tanaike's suggestion work for you?